# Problems with generic Double-Ended Priority Queue

Tags: java, linked-list, queue, doubly-linked-list

I'm having a lot of troubles with an assignment for my data structures class. I need to implement a double ended priority queue using a doubly linkedList but the code that my professor provided for testing it has some weird stuff in it. The part that I don't understand is why is he using DoubleEndedPriorityQueue but then adds objects instead of Integers. The error that I'm getting is that there is no method add(object) which is true.

```
public class Test1ForAssign2 {
public static void main(final String[] args) {

final DoubleEndedPriorityQueue<Integer> sampleL = (DoubleEndedPriorityQueue<Integer>)new ListDoubleEndedPriorityQueue();

sampleL.add((Object)5);
sampleL.add((Object)12);
sampleL.add((Object)5);
sampleL.add((Object)1);
sampleL.add((Object)(-7));
sampleL.add((Object)3);
System.out.println("Priority Queue Contents: ");
System.out.println("Deleting: " + sampleL.deleteMin());
System.out.println("Deleting: " + sampleL.deleteMax());
}

public interface DoubleEndedPriorityQueue<AnyType>{
void makeEmpty ( );
void add (AnyType x);
AnyType deleteMin ( );
AnyType deleteMax ( );
AnyType findMin ( );
AnyType findMax ( );
boolean isEmpty ( );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you say, this code currently won't compile - you need to either make `sampleL` into a `DoubleEndedPriorityQueue<Object>`, or cast the ints to Integer instead:

```
sampleL.add((Integer)5);
```

There's also a nicer way to get the wrapper types:

```
sampleL.add(Integer.valueOf(5));
```

I'd think the intention here was probably to avoid implicit autoboxing - java will automatically convert between wrapper and primitive types, but it's good to make this explicit.  Especially where generics are concerned this can get quite confusing, and (especially when learning) it's good to not rely on those shortcuts.

Comment: Thanks @hugh that's what I thought. btw can you please help me with something else? he also gave us this code:

  private Comparator<? super AnyType> cmp;
  private Node<AnyType> first = null;
  private Node<AnyType> last  = null;
but I have no idea how to use a comparator, I have been trying to do cmp.compare(obj1, obj2) but it always give me a nullpoint exception and i'm sure that both objects are not null. I think it is because the class Integer does not implements comparator but then how does he expects us to do it?

Comment: (Generally it's bad practice to post several questions in one place, but I'll try to give some pointers)  Integer doesn't implement Comparator, but it does implement Comparable - if you search for those you should be able to find articles on how these differ.  `compare` can throw NPE if either of the arguments is null, otherwise that sounds like the code in `compare` is incorrect (probably uses a nullable field without null-checking).  Are you using a debugger?  Using one will make your life *hugely* better.